# How to use System.Threading.Tasks in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm learning F#. Recently, I read about the improvement about .NET 4.5 about tasks.
So, I took a peek at how to use it in F#.
In fsi:

```
use System.Threading.Tasks
Parallel.ForEach([1;2],fun x->x+1);;
```

Gives a lot of errors.

In addition, in the source code of Fsharp core lib. I saw:

```
module Parallel =
open System.Threading.Tasks

[<CompiledName("Choose")>]
let choose f (array: 'T[]) = 
  checkNonNull "array" array
  let inputLength = array.Length
  let lastInputIndex = inputLength - 1

  let isChosen : bool [] = //(Deliberately offside to avoid scrollbars)
       Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.zeroCreateUnchecked inputLength
  let results : 'U [] = 
       Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.zeroCreateUnchecked inputLength
```

However, I am unable to use Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.Array.zeroCreateUnchecked. Why?
I got:

> error FS1092: The type 'Array' is not accessible from this code
>   location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your use of `ForEach` method is confusing, because your lambda function returns a result. The `ForEach` operation can be used to perform some *imperative action* for all element from the input, so the lambda function should return `unit`. The following will work fine:

```
open System.Threading.Tasks 

Parallel.ForEach([1;2], fun x-> 
  printfn "%d" (x+1)) |> ignore
```

I also added `ignore`, because `ForEach` returns some value as a result (and we don't use it).

Regarding the F# core library code - the code is compiled as part of F# core library, so it can use some internal functions that are not exposed in the public API and so you can't use them. In your case, you'll need to use `Array.zeroCreate` instead of `Array.zeroCreateUnchecked`.